# Combine one to many lists into one flat list of objects C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

So here is the issue I am facing. I have a one to many list relationship.
Here are examples of how the lists would look.

The objects in list 1 are dynamic and have a few properties with the most important one being "id".
The second list has a defined object looking something like this "id" "value desc" "actual value".
The second list can have many rows belonging to the first list. The "value desc" is the property name and the "actual value".

I need to combine these lists into something that looks like this. An object with all list 1 properties and all corresponding rows in the second list. If the second list had 3 items belonging to an item in list 1 then the new object should have all properties of list 1 along with all the rows gathered from list 2 in a flat structure like way.

Data examples

Table 1:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bob |
| 2 | joe |

Table 2

| id | propname | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | length | 2 |
| 1 | age | 12 |
| 1 | haircolor | blue |
| 2 | length | 5 |
| 2 | age | 90 |
| 2 | haircolor | red |

How I want the data to look

| id | name | length | haircolor | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | 2 | blue | 12 |
| 2 | joe | 5 | red | 90 |

Currently, I have this working.

```
 public IEnumerable<dynamic> test(List<dynamic> data, List<modal> 
                                     dataset)//closest
        {
          var query = (from a in data
                       join b in dataset
                       on a.id equals b.id into t
                       select new {
                         a, 
                         t
                       });
    
          return query;
        }
```

However, the result is an object with properties of list 1 and then a property on that object that is an array of items found in list 2. I need these items to not be in an array and be property names with values on the new created object.

I hope my explanation was clear enough!

Comment: Would you provide some sample input and output data?

Comment: Sure, see this image https://ibb.co/B2DJm2P I think it will help loads. As you can see the return quesry var has the properties of the objects in the first list and an array of the objects on the second. What I need is all the properties of the second list to not be in an array. The reason is for some processing I do else where on the system. I basically just want to straight up loop through the query  without sub loops to access the objects in the array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Would update the quesion with the input and output data in tablular form (not an image). See this link for more details - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: done and dusted hope it helps

Comment: What result would you expect if you had different setts of properties for different IDs?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [expandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JonasH The challenge here is that in our system the items on the second list is defined by users. So they can create "optional fields" as many times as they want. So in theory we could be looking at an additional 30 properties based on the user usage. Im not sure exactly what you mean by what results I expect. But the result I want is a flat object build of the properties in list 1 and all the rows in the second list as properties on say object we are building. I want a clean object I can iterate through and do stuff without creating sub loops to loop through the array of optional fields.

Comment: I'm asking how you would handle if joe an age, and nothing else, and bob had an skinColor property. What age has bob? none? 0? What happens if joe has has two age properties? Do pick the first one? is it an error? the highest? If your model allow for such issues you need to consider how to handle them.

Comment: the objects do not have to be identical in terms of properties. And in the case of a duplicate property for joe grabbing anyone is fine. And if joe does not have a certain property it simply wouldn't even be in the second list to begin with. I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivolt table :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "bob" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "bob" });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("propname", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("value", typeof(object));
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "length", 2 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "age", 12 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "haircolor", "blue"});
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "length", 5 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "age", 90 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "haircolor", "red" });

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();

            string[] properties = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("propname")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
            pivot.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            pivot.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            DataColumn[] columns = properties.Select(x => new DataColumn(x, typeof(object))).ToArray();
            pivot.Columns.AddRange(columns);

            var joins = from id1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                         join id2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on id1.Field<int>("id") equals id2.Field<int>("id")
                         select new { id = id1.Field<int>("id"), name = id1.Field<string>("name"), id2 = id2 };

            var groups = joins.GroupBy(x => x.id);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["id"] = group.Key;
                newRow["name"] = group.First().name;

                foreach (var row in group)
                {
                    newRow[row.id2.Field<string>("propname")] = row.id2.Field<object>("value");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The only constraint here is that I would need prior knowledge of the property names. Unfortunately in my case I do not have that knowledge. As the list of potential properties in the second list could be anything as this is defined on a user level. Im sure you can start to see my predicament here xD. EDIT. nevermind I see I can actually create properties on the second table dynamically. I will play around with your solution! Ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: The only two property names that are needed is the id and the names.  The property names are found using following : string[] properties = dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("propname")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();